# How to manipulate data after received as AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello everyone I am building a Music download website where i offer users to download songs.
Let's disclose the whole scenario.
I have a menu where each menuItem has a link and each link has been given a unique id. Based on the link clicked, with the help of the id, I am preparing the parameter which is the absolute path for the file to be downloaded and I am retrieving this with ajax where i am getting the responsed data displayed in a table. But I am not able maniplate this data which I obtain through ajax. Please help me.

My code looks like:
I am calling this function on each menuclick which gets the absolute path for the Movie song request.

```
function call(i) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "./SongsDemoList.jsp?path=" + document.getElementById(i).value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Now Here SongsDemoList has a anchor tag for each songs but i am unable to click the link.
plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

The xmlhttp object has an attribute called the responseText, which is the text the server sent back, if any.

The onReadyStateChange function currently sets the innerHTML of an element with the id of 'placeholder', to the received text, but you can do anything to the xmlhttp object's responseText. For example, if you have a loadVideo function, which can load a video based on what the server sent back, you can call it like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        loadVideo(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```